# The value in CS is 1FD0h what is the location of next instruction from 00000h if Instruction pointer is 3CD4h

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

I'm trying to find answer of this question.

I tested in Emu8086, when I use MOV, ADD, SUB, MUL,... instructions, the next value of IP increase by 2, but when I use CWD instruction, IP's value increase by 1.

So in this question, I don't know how it actually work.

> The value in CS is 1FD0h
> What is the location of next instruction from 00000h if Instruction pointer is 3CD4h

Is it 1FD0-3CD5 or 1FD0-3CD6?

Comment: x86 instructions have varying length, as you've found.

Comment: You are probably only expected to give the starting location, and they want you to do the real mode address translation calculating the physical address instead of the segment:offset. PS: if you use emu8086 why did you tag nasm? In any case, the assembler is not relevant, I have removed the tag.

Comment: "next instruction **from 00000h**" is very weird phrasing, not at all clear.  As @Jester says, you could find the linear address (cs_base + IP) of the start of the first instruction, where cs_base = CS*16 in real mode.  If they'd just said "next instruction", that could make sense as another way of saying "first instruction", like what the CPU will decode next if IP currently has that value (after a jump or between instructions).  But "next from 00000h"?  Oh, that's 5 hex digits, so 20 bits.  Probably they are asking for a linear address, distance from `0000:0000` = `00000h`.